# как узнать модель материнской платы через php

Tags: php

как узнать модель материнской платы и вообще любого железа на компе клиента
который зашел на сайт **php** ?

Comment: К сожалению это невозможно

Comment: К счастью это невозможно, можно узнать только некоторые косвенно относящиеся к железу вещи, вроде размера экрана и наличия или отсутствие geolocation итп

Comment: Вывести форму, с вопросом Клиенту, что бы он написал, что за мат. плата у него)))

Comment: он сам не знает это же клиент )))

Comment: получается клиенту запустить у себя на компьютере ваше по, которое отправит Вам отчет

Comment: да удобно же было бы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Средствами ActiveX только если, как на сайте Nvidia, но это надо иметь сертификат подписанный.

Comment: И работать будет только под виндой.

Comment: Там же nvidia получает инфу о версии винды и какая видяха.. Мне кажется там иначе работает, типо софт сам отправляет данные при запросе, но это не точно))